# How to generate two random 1 in one unsigned char in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, random

I need to generate a mask vector (unsigned char type) which contains 2 of '1's only, i.e. 0x03, 0x50 and etc.

I also need these two '1's distributed randomly in the vector.

How can I do this in c/c++?

Thank you!

Edit:
A more challenging and general case is asked here.
[How to generate n random 1s in an unsigned char array in c/c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749497/how-to-generate-n-random-1s-in-an-unsigned-char-array-in-c-c)

Comment: Pick a random number from 1 to 8. Then pick a random number from 1 to 7.

Comment: Could you elaborate? How does this help?

Comment: Well, then you switch the corresponding two bits on...

Comment: How often do you need to generate this vector? Maybe you setup a table with valid values and then generate a random index into that table.

Comment: minimum coding is the concern...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do like this:

```
srand(time(0));
int s[8];
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) s[i] = i;
// s[0], s[1] are two random locations for '1's
u = rand()%8;
swap(s[0], s[u]);
v = rand()%7+1;
swap(s[1], s[v]);
unsigned char c = (1 << s[0]) | (1 << s[1]);
```

Comment: By the way, this is called Fisher-Yates shuffling, it is used to shuffle a deck of cards, or randomly select k elements out of N elements.

Comment: Does this prevent u,v to be the same value?

Comment: No, we want s[0], s[1] be different values. Notice the last line.

Comment: No, it won't, there is swap there.

Comment: oh, I see. I think this can be extended to multiple 1 bits. what is the purpose of v = rand()%7+1? Since you have the swap, v = rand()%8 probably work too?

Comment: Indeed, it can be extended to multiple 1 bits. The purpose of v=rand()%7+1 is to ensure equal probability. I don't have time now to elaborate, just google 'Fisher-Yates shuffle' to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like homework.  Here's a solution that requires only one random number generation per value and also requires C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int data[] =
{
    3,
    5,
    6,
    9,
    10,
    12,
    17,
    18,
    20,
    24,
    33,
    34,
    36,
    40,
    48,
    65,
    66,
    68,
    72,
    80,
    96,
    129,
    130,
    132,
    136,
    144,
    160,
    192
};

int main()
{
    std::mt19937_64 eng;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        std::cout << data[dist(eng)] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I like the code. But I can only give one correct answer...I just asked a similar question, but more challenging. You can take a look.

Comment: This code does not compile on my computer. It complains about not finding <random>. Any hints? Thank you!

Comment: <random> is new in C++11.  I don't know if you're compiler supports it yet or not.

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.5.2, it is pretty recent.

Comment: This link: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.tr1 indicates you may find it as a TR1 library.  Try `<tr1/random>` and `std::try::mt19937_64`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want I think

```
srand(time(0));
int shift=rand() % 8;
char odd=0x3 << shift;
```

Comment: I think two '1' don't need to be consecutive based on my understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, the two '1's are adjacent to each other in your case. I need them to be randomly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick a random number between 0 and 7. Raise 2 to that number.
2. Pick another random number between 0 and 7 (repeat if you got the same number as in one).
3. Raise 2 to your second number and add it to the first.

Some pseudo-code:

```
   int rand1 = random(7);
   unsigned char mask = pow(2, rand1);

   int rand2 = 0;
   do {
       rand2 = random(7);
   } while (rand2 == rand1);

   mask += pow(2, rand2);
```

Note that shifting a bit by your random numbers would have the same outcome as raising two to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
int idx1 = rand() % 8;
int idx2 = rand() % 8;
while(idx1 == idx2) idx2 = rand() % 8;
unsigned char c = (1 << idx1) + (1<<idx2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 2 bits to be non consecutive this should work too

```
srand(time(0));
size_t count=0;
unsigned char c=0;
while(count<2)
{
     char shift=rand() % 8;
     if(!(shift & c))
     {
        c|=shift;
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note in theory this could possible cause an endless loop though

Comment: I think you want to use if(!(shift ^ c))?

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
// One random bit from the full range
int rand1 = rand() % 8;
// One random bit from the seven remaining
int rand2 = (rand() % 7 + rand1 + 1) % 8;
// Construct the result!
char c = (1 << rand1) + (1 << rand2);
```

No loops, pretty minimal number of operations. Of course, ott's suggestion in the comments is actually quite good: there are 8*7/2 = 28 possible results, and 28 bytes is a pretty paltry amount of memory, so if it's a repeated operation you could just store them and randomly pick one.

Comment: I think this is neat...but what if I want to have three 1 bits?

Comment: @rex: John Yang's solution (well, Fisher-Yates shuffling) is the general algorithm. This is just a nice shortcut for the particular case you asked about.