# How to generate n random 1s in an unsigned char array in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, random

This is a different question from the one I just asked and it is more challenging.

I have an unsigned char array, say 
unsigned char A[16].
I need to generate a mask vector which i will apply to my array A[16].

It should contain n number of '1's, where 0 < n < 16*8 (The mask vector can be an array B[16] as long as there are n number of '1's in the array)

I also need these n number of '1's distributed randomly in the vector.

How can I do this in c/c++?

Thank you!

Edit:
My thought is as follows: 
I will generate n random numbers (checking needs to be done to make sure all n numbers are not the same) and store them in array tmp[n]. Then mask is generated based on shifting.

```
srand(time(0));
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < i; j++) 
    while(tmp[i] == tmp[j])  // to make sure all n random numbers are different
      tmp[i] = rand()%128;

unsigned char mask[16] 
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  mask[16] |= (1 << tmp[i]);  //generate mask
```

Comment: You stated your requirements pretty nicely, but you did'nt specify what you have done and what are your ideas on solving this.This looks like Homework & unless you post your efforts,this will be closed pretty soon.

Comment: It is not homework...But I can post my effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate random `(i,j)` pair of numbers, where `i < 16` and `j < 8`.  If the bit at position `B[i]&(1<<j)` is not set, set it and increment "count".  Loop until "count" reaches "n".

A bit of code (untested):

```
void generate_n_bit_mask ( unsigned char B[], int n )
{
    // avoid infinite loop later on.
    for ( int i=0; (i < 16); ++i ) {
        B[i] = 0;
    }
    // invariant: k is number of currently masked bits.
    for ( int k = 0; (k < n); )
    {
        // select bit at random.
        int i = rand() % 16;
        int j = rand() %  8;
        unsigned char mask = 1 << j;
        // set it if not selected previously.
        if ( (B[i]&mask) == 0 ) {
            B[i] |= mask, ++k;
        }
    }
}
```

Exercise,  for the challenge: remove magic constant `16` from the code.

**Edit**: The modification suggested in your comments contains a nasty bug.  Here is a test program to play with the way bits are distributed in your output mask.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

void generate_n_bit_mask ( unsigned char B[], int n )
{
    // avoid infinite loop later on.
    for ( int i=0; (i < 16); ++i ) {
        B[i] = 0;
    }
    // invariant: k is number of currently masked bits.
    for ( int k = 0; (k < n); )
    {
        // select bit at random.
        int i = std::rand() % 16;
        int j = std::rand() %  8;
        unsigned char mask = 1 << j;
        // set it if not selected previously.
        if ( (B[i]&mask) == 0 ) {
            B[i] |= mask, ++k;
        }
    }
    int j = 0;
}

// count number of set bits in a byte.
int bit_count ( unsigned char x )
{
    int n = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; (i < 8); ++i ) {
        n += ((x >> i) & 1);
    }
    return (n);
}

// count number of set bits in 16 bytes.
int total_bit_count ( unsigned char B[] )
{
    int n = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; (i < 16); ++i ) {
        n += bit_count(B[i]);
    }
    return (n);
}

int main ( int, char ** )
{
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    unsigned char B[16];
    // for all possible values of "n"
    for ( int i = 0; (i <= 16*8); ++i )
    {
        // generate a 16 byte mask with "n" set bits.
        generate_n_bit_mask(B, i);
        // verify that "n" bits are set.
        int n = total_bit_count(B);
        if ( n != i ) {
            std::cout << i << ": " << n << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

When this program is run, it will try every value of `n` from `0` to `16*8` and generate a random mask with `n` bits, then verify that exactly `n` bits are set.  If any error occurs (for some value of `n`, some `k!=n` bits are set), a message is output.

If I change the condition to `if ( (B[i]^mask) != 0 )`, I get consistent errors in the output.  Every run produces at least 1 error message.  The original condition `if ( (B[i]&mask) == 0 )` consistently produces 0 error messages.

Comment: Do you really need a comma operator there?

Comment: It should rather be `j` instead of `(j-1)`.

Comment: @K-ballo: Yes.  It emphasizes that the two instructions are actually one logical step in the algorithm.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. Because if n = 2, I can have two 1s in B[0]. If you change to `if ( B[i]^mask != 0)`. Then it works.

Comment: @rex: that change contains a bug: you won't be able to insert more than `n=16` bits in the total sequence.  Besides, your inputs will no longer be distributed "randomly" with the same definition of "random" (without replacement at the bit level or at the byte level).

Comment: @rex: added test program to demonstrate validity of output mask.  Your modified condition doesn't work.

Comment: @AndréCaron: When was the last time you looked at an implementation and went "Hmm, this algorithm only says there's one step here, but there are two semi-colons here. What am I missing?"  Save it for the IOCCC.

Comment: @AndréCaron: your solution is correct! I should check more carefully.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: While I totally understand that people disagree with the choice of a comma over a semi-colon, I fail to see how this code is obfuscated, or anything like the stuff submitted to the IOCCC.  Using a comma instead of semi-colon here is akin to the commonly accepted practice of adding the redundant `virtual` keyword in front of an virtual method override.  Extra hints are always welcome, especially when they don't cost anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of 16 `unsigned char`s, which can be seen as 16 * 8 bits. To generate a random mask with `n` 1 bits in it, generate a random position in the range [0, 16*8) and set the corresponding bit to 1. If the bit was previously zero, then you have just added a bit to the array. Repeat this until you have added `n` bits.